# How is device-responsive layer selection working for you?

Tags: carto

I ran into problems getting layer selection to work with data categories that I didn't document well in this process, but I would just like to show my results here in case people are interested in adding responsive navigation buttons to their maps. Here is my result: http://jsbin.com/sihayino/4/edit (Ultimately, I'd like to add a custom base map—still figuring out how to keep the delicate balance I have here while adding that icing to my cake).

Has anyone a better method for incorporating layer toggling for viewing map layers on mobile devices/tablets? If not, it's no big deal. I'm pretty ok with this.

Comment: Great that you share your experiences! Could you first post a question outlining what you tried to achieve and what your problem was, and then add this text as an (accepted) answer? That will better follow the format of this page.

Comment: Welcome to our site! Although this is nominally a question, its actual content is buried in the link. This means the question cannot stand on its own and could become incomprehensible if the link ever changes. If you would genuinely like suggestions for better methods, then please explicitly describe your current method in this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's late, but there is an example in CartoDB.js working with filters.

https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/tree/develop/examples/filters-template

Hope it helps.